# Count number of words in a .txt file in C

Tags: c, file-io

My program needs to take in the file name as a command line parameter and then count the number of words in the file. However, I'm struggling with how to count words instead of characters. Here's my code so far:

```
int readFile(char *fileName);
void correctNumOfArgs(const int argc);

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  int numWords;
  correctNumOfArgs(argc);

  numWords = readFile(argv[1]);
  printf("There are %d word(s).\n", numWords);

  return 0;
}

int readFile(char *fileName) {
  int counter = 0;

  FILE *file = fopen(fileName, "r");

  if (file == NULL) {
    printf("There are 0 word(s).\n");
    exit(0);
  }

  char c;

  while (!feof(file)) {
    do {
      fscanf(file, "%c", &c);
      if (c == '\0') {
        printf("There are 0 word(s).\n");
        exit(0);
      }
    } while (!isspace(c));
    ++counter;
  }

  fclose(file);

  return counter;

}
```

Note: the program correctNumOfArgs just checks if argc == 2 or not.

My main problem is that my program counts more words than there are contained in the file. For example, in a text file that just contains "hello!" my program returns that there are 2 words instead of just 1. I'm not really sure where my error is, can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: `while (!feof(file))` loops once too often - `feof` won't return true until after you try to read past the end of the file.  Check the result of `fscanf` instead - it will return the number of items successfully read and assigned, or `EOF` if it sees end of file.

Comment: Just loop with `while (fscanf(file, "%255s", buffer) == 1)` with a buffer of size 256. As `%s ` returns one word on each read and automatically skips over spaces and other blanks character, you will easily get the number of words (and words larger than 255 characters are very uncommon in all languages I know...)